# Location API not working for custom/third-party applications

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gps, rim-4.2, jsr179

I'm trying to write a simple GPS based application for my BB 8800 (with Airtel, India).

But for some reason my code getLocation(timeout) always returns with a non-valid location (only after timing out). I tried different combinations of criteria parameters with no success.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is not with my code because even the BlackBerry GPS demo application does not work. However, my GPS receiver is working fine because "Wayfinder", a maps application that came bundled with my BB, works fine.

To test it further, I tried running SpotFinder and Google Maps. But they did not work either. Google Maps could determine location using cell tower info but not GPS.

Here are some more details about my environment,
 1. Phone Model: BlackBerry 8800
 2. Carrier:     AirTel (India)
 3. Device Version: 4.2.168 (Platform 2.3.0.54)

Can my carrier block it? [I spoke with AirTel technical support but they wouldn't budge to help developers]

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Some carriers (like Verizon US) blocked GPS for third party applications. Others just enabled GPS for a white list of applications (mostly their own) but deny access to GPS for all others.

It seems your provider is doing such things.

Answer (score 0):

Can your carrier block it? Absolutely, I don't know about in India, but in the U.S. some carriers can and do restrict applications from accessing the GPS if they are not "approved." That seems quite likely given the scenario you described.